Prove that $\det(A) = \det(D)$ where $D$ is the diagonalizable matrix of its Dunford decomposition

$\mathbf{E}$ is a $\mathbb{K}-$vector space.
Let $A,D,N \in M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ such that $D$ is diagonalizable, $N$ is nilpotent,
$DN=ND$ and $A = D+N$ (also known as Dunford decomposition). Prove that $\det(A) = \det(D)$.

I study math in french so I'll try to translate the keywords accordingly. My take on this is as follows.
$D$ is diagonalizable, then $\displaystyle E = \oplus_{\lambda \in sp(D)} E_{\lambda}(D)$, choose $B$ a basis of $E$ adapted to the previous direct sum. Let $f,d,g$ be the endomorphisms associated respectively to the matrices $A,D,N$ in the basis $B$.
We can see that $(f-d)^{n} = 0$ because $g$ is nilpotent, and $\forall \lambda \in sp(d), \forall x \in E_{\lambda}(g):(f-\lambda Id_{E})^{n}(x) = 0$
$\forall \lambda \in sp(d)$, Let $f_{\lambda}$ be the endomorphism of $\ker(f-\lambda Id_{E})^{n}$ induced by $f$.
if $\alpha$ is an eigenvalue of $f_{\lambda}$ and $x$ is an eigenvector associated to $\alpha$ then $f_{\lambda}(x) = f(x)= \alpha x$, and because $(X-\lambda)^{n}$ is a cancelling polynomial of $f_{\lambda}$ then $(f-\lambda Id_{E})^{n}(x) = (\alpha-\lambda)^{n}x=0$, hence $\alpha = \lambda$
By this, we can conclude that $\lambda \in sp(d) \implies \lambda \in sp(f)$.
Now for the other way, if $\lambda \in sp(f)$, by choosing $x$ its eigenvector we have $f(x) = d(x) + g(x) \implies d(x)-\lambda x = g(x) \implies (d-\lambda Id_{E})^{n}(x) = 0$. This means that $(X-\lambda)^{n}$ is a cancelling polynomial of $d$, hence $\lambda \in sp(d)$.
We finally conclude that $sp(d) = sp(f)$, and at last, $\det(d) = \det(f)$ (because the determinant is the product of all the eigenvalues).
I want to know if my proof is correct, and if there is any shortcut / improvement to make it clearer.

The opening 2 sentences are not correctly stated.  Consider $D= \left[\begin{matrix}1 & 1\1 & -1\end{matrix}\right]$ and $N=\left[\begin{matrix}1 & 1\-1 & -1\end{matrix}\right]
$

A couple of things. First, as stated, the statement isn't true. $D = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ has the eigenbasis $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$, and $N = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ is nilpotent, but $N+D = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ has a different determinant. You need to include the crucial assumption that $D,N$ commute. Without this assumption, you cannot know that $f, g$ will respect the direct sum split at all. But with it, you know that $g|_{E_\lambda}:E_\lambda \rightarrow E_\lambda$. So the whole problem "splits" and becomes checking that $\det(\lambda I_n - N) = \lambda^n$ if $N$ is nilpotent, which is what happens on each summand. For this statement, you can use Jordan canonical form.
Second, knowing that the $sp(A) = sp(B)$ does not imply $\det(A) = \det(B)$, because of multiplicities. That is, if the eigenvalues of $A$ are $[1,2,2]$ and the eigenvalues of $B$ are $[1,1,2]$, then of course the two sets are the same, but the products are not.

Thanks, I understand now. I will type out another answer matching your ideas.

Let $f,d,g$ be the endomorphisms associated respectively to the matrices $A,D,N$ in a basis $B$ of $E$.
Since $d$ is diagonizable, then $E = \oplus_{\lambda \in sp(d)}E_{\lambda}(d)$. $\forall \lambda \in sp(d),$ define $g_{\lambda}$ the endomorphism of $E_{\lambda}(d)$ induced from $g$ (since $g$ and $d$ commute then $E_{\lambda}(d)$ is stable by $g$).   We have $g_{\lambda} = f-\lambda Id_{E}$, and because $g$ is nilpotent then $g_{\lambda}$ is also nilpotent, meaning that $X^{n}$ is a cancelling polynomial for $g_{\lambda}$, hence $sp(g_{\lambda}) = \{ 0 \}$. Note $n_{\lambda}=\dim(E_{\lambda}(d))$, then $\chi_{g_{\lambda}}=X^{n_{\lambda}}$, and using the kernel lemma : $\ker(X^{n_{\lambda}}(f))=E_{\lambda}(d) \implies E_{\lambda}(d)=\ker(f-\lambda Id_{E})^{n_{\lambda}}$. As such $E = \oplus_{\lambda \in sp(d)}\ker(f-\lambda Id_{E})^{n_{\lambda}}$
(Im not quite sure of this next line), we can conclude that $\chi_{f}=\prod_{\lambda \in sp(d)}(X-\lambda)^{n_{\lambda}}$, meaning that $\det(f)= \prod_{\lambda \in sp(d)}\lambda^{n_\lambda}= \det(d)$
